# Rails 4: ActiveRecords can't save data from JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to save data from JSON request that I am sending on my server. I already added exceptions to *CSRF* defender and it passes requests.
*ActiveRecords* **doesn't save data** from it, but it does for HTML requests.

I use **curl** to generate JSON requests

```
curl  -v -X POST -d '{"claim": {"lastname":"Jhon Smith","phone":"+1(51)555555","latitude":"10.4","longitude":"12.7","theme":"Test message","text":"Text of test message"}}'  -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" http://localhost:3000/claims/new
```

It returns message code 200.

```
> POST /claims/new HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Content-Type:application/json
> Accept:application/json
> Content-Length: 167
> 
* upload completely sent off: 167 out of 167 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Cache-Control: no-cache
```

> Server answered that it caught data but didn't do anything.

```
Started POST "/claims/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-16 01:35:24 +0300
Processing by ClaimsController#new as JSON
  Parameters: {"claim"=>{"lastname"=>"Jhon Smith", "phone"=>"+1(51)555555", "latitude"=>"10.4", "longitude"=>"12.7", "theme"=>"Test message", "text"=>"Text of test message"}}
  Rendered claims/new.json.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

There is code of my controller that trying to save *JSON*:

```
def create
  @claim = Claim.new(claim_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @claim.save
      format.html do
        redirect_to acceptedclaim_path
        flash[:success] = "Ваша заява прийнята! Дякуємо за допомогу!"
      end
      format.json do
        render json: @claim, status: :created, location: @claim
      end
    else
      format.html do
        redirect_to new_claim_path
        flash[:danger] = flash_errors(@claim)
      end
      format.json do
        render json: @claim.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end
  end
end

def claim_params
  params.require(:claim).permit(:lastname, :phone, :latitude, :longitude, :theme, :text)
end
```

I access POST via next config in router

```
post   'claims/new' => 'claims#new'
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST /claims/new` is hitting the `new` action in your controller, but in your example you defined the `create` action.

To fix, add this to your routes if it isn't already present:

`post   'claims' => 'claims#create'`

And target the  `POST /claims` action with the same params.